# Can't set headers after they are sent with Firebase & Express

Tags: node.js, express, firebase

My problem seems to be exactly like the problem posted in this question here:

[Very similar problem on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889162/node-js-express-firebase-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

I am simply posting new blog data to a Firebase DB. The data is successfully saved to the database every time. Works as expected. However, when trying to send a response back to the client, I get this error:

```
   Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
   at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
   at ServerResponse.header
```

This topic has been covered in many questions before, but I can't figure out where headers are being written to in my code. Is this a bug with Firebase?

Here is my code:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
  var rawtitle = req.body.title;
  var author = req.body.author;
  var headline = req.body.headline; 
  var body = req.body.blogtext; 
  var time = Date.now(); 
  var slug = convertToSlug(rawtitle);

  postsDB.push().set({ 
    'title': rawtitle,
    'headline' : headline,
    'slug' : slug,  
    'body': body,
    'created' : time,
    'author' : author
       }, onComplete);

  function onComplete(){
   //following log statement is always false 
   console.log("Have the headers been sent:", res.headersSent); 
   res.send({redirect: '/blog'})
  }

});
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have any other routes or middleware that might also be firing on the same request?  Also, what is `postsDB` and what do `.push()` and `.set()` do?

Comment: This route seems ok. There is nothing wrong with it. I Believe you are looking at wrong place. Try and put `morgan` log with your express app and see which resource generates this issue.